# Python - Collections

Tags: python

Am new to Python, and would like to know, how to store list of different DataTypes inside a dictionary with a Key

for Example -

```
{[Key1,int1,int1,String1] , [Key2,int2,int2,String2], [Key3,int3,int3,String3] }
```

how to create Dictionary and add these elements?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you meant that your data is:

```
lst = [[Key1,int1,int1,String1] , [Key2,int2,int2,String2], [Key3,int3,int3,String3]]
```

Then you could do something like:

```
{x[0]:x[1:] for x in lst}
```

What you actually have up there is an attempt to create a `set` out of a bunch of lists -- and that won't work because `list` objects aren't hashable.